# Goto in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I want to create a MySQL stored procedure that contain a series of conditions to be checked.

```
IF (a && b) then
  IF c =1 then
    IF d < e then
      check conditions 1,2,3...
    END IF
  ELSE
    check conditions 1,2,3...
  END IF
END IF
```

I want to write the procedure in such a way that condition 1,2,3 should be written as common so that procedure will be like

```
IF (a && b) then
 IF c =1 then
   IF d < e then
     goto label check;
   END IF
 ELSE
   goto label check;
 END IF
END IF 

label:label check;
  check conditions 1,2,3...
```

Since goto is not present in MySQL stored procedure, how can I write the procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF a AND b THEN
  IF c = 1 AND d < e OR c != 1 then
    check conditions 1,2,3...
  END IF
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using `goto`, even when available (*).

You code can be simplified as follows:

```
IF a AND b AND (c != 1 OR d < e) THEN
    check conditions
END IF
```

Also, mixing litteral (`AND`, `OR`) boolean operators and their symbolic counterparts (`&&`, `||`) makes your code look odd (but this is just my opinion).

*Just to avoid a flame war, yes sometimes a little goto is not that bad, but this is a perfect example of a goto abuse*